# How do I set up the values for the x axis in matplot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, data-science

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(data['Unemployment Rate'])
plt.axis([1948,2017,0,15])
plt.show()
```

These code returned an empty graph.

The table contains 2 columns, data['Year'] and data['Unemployment Rate'].

The year is between 1948 and 2017.

What I am trying to accomplish is to generate a graph for the unemployment rate and use the values in data['Year'] as the value of the x axis.

Comment: As you say you want to use "the values in data['Year'] as the value of the x axis"; yet you do not inform matplotlib about this desire. Like "I want to plot `y` against `x`, so I tried `plt.plot(y)`"; but where is `x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to plot `y` against `x`, you need to inform matplotlib to do so.

```
plt.plot(x,y)
```

If instead you only call `plt.plot(y)`, matplotlib would not know that you want to plot against the `x` data. Instead it would take the numbers 0,1,...N-1 to plot against.

Comment: Note that I searched for 10 minutes on a duplicate for this one (because this sure must have happened to people before already) but didn't find any. So I provided this answer. But if someone finds one please inform me such that this can be closed.

Comment: It's maybe because one would only have to read the first few sentences of the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) to solve this problem ...

Comment: @ThomasKühn Sure ;-) But since many people don't even read that first sentence before asking a question here, I would still expect there to be a question about that somewhere. Problem is, what search terms would one use to find that?

Comment: That's why you got my upvote :D. I didn't find anything either.